# SQLAlchemy: How to change a MySQL server system variable using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to set the general_log and general_log_file variables using SQLAlchemy, is there a way to do this? I've been Googling around and can't find anything on the topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute any raw SQL query which you need (of course you have to get appropriate rights in the session). To change a variable run something like this:

```
# change variable name and values to what you need
connection.execute("SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it through a session rather than through a connection? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, you could use the following code the set a variable using the raw [`Connection`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection) object.

```py
connection.execute("SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF")
```

If you have a [`Session`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session) object, you can retrieve the underlying `Connection` object using the [`Session.connection()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.connection) function.

So your code could look as follows.

```py
session.connection().execute("SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF")
```